# Nested collection view Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have view controller which has one horizontal  collection view which has three cells. Inside each cell I have one vertical collection view which has 2 section. 1st section has one cell and 2  nd section is Dynamics It can have any number of cells.  In first section of vertical collection view which has one cell it has one horizontal collection view which can have any number of cells.

Issue : when innermost collection view which is inside first section of vertical collection view is scrolling, and when it reaches end of collection view I want to disable the scrolling so that my outer most collection view which has three cells can scroll, and immediately after that I want to enable the scrolling of innermost collection view. So that it can scroll again. It's like scroll view or collection view

[image: Nested Collection View]

Comment: When you say disabling the scrolling, do you mean disabling the scrolling both ways(left to right and right to left) ?

Comment: can you please share the screen shot what exactly you need.

Comment: @pooja Yes. I need it to stop working when I reach at the last cell of gray collection view, If I stop scrolling of inner collection view it will automatically scroll to next cell of outer collection view(Red). But I want event Which recognise last cell. and when it stop it will scroll to next but after reaching to next cell of red collection view I want to enable the scrolling of grey collection view

Comment: @VDPurohit . Please check screens shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here is a similar example ,which has collection view within another collection view cell

[GitHub sample](https://github.com/pooja-kamath/CollectionViewWithinCollectionViewCell)

Here I am trying to get the last cell displayed event in the inner collection view and disabling the scroll.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Checking if its not the inner collection view
        if(collectionView.restorationIdentifier != "Collection")
        {
            //scrolled till datasource.count -1 == 14 in our case
            if( indexPath.row == 14){

                //Disabling the scrolling
                collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false;

                //Saved the collection view , so that the scrolling can be enabled later.
                scrolldisabledCollectionView = collectionView;
            }
        }

    }
```

And when the outer collection view is scrolled, The inner collection view is enabled.

```
 override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        if(collectionView?.restorationIdentifier == "Collection")
        {
            scrolldisabledCollectionView?.isScrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Scrolling in 2 collection view is working automatically, but I need answer for three collection view. Innermost collection view is delegate and datasource of vertical cell which is at indexpath section 0 and cell 0. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please specify which is the third collection view in the image uploaded in the question and what's the direction of flow of the third collection view

Comment: Gray color is the inner most collection view and I want to start and stop the scrolling of this collection only when it reaches at the start of end of scrolling.  And start again once it's scroll the outer collection view which is in red. It will happen automatically. I just want to stop and start scrolling of gray collection view.

Comment: I have tried with three collections view ,It works you can get the sample from here https://github.com/pooja-kamath/TripleCollectionView